# how to mark a task as archived with the asana api?

Tags: asana

If i just mark a task as completed, it still gets returned each time I query for tasks, forcing me to process the same task each time I call the tasks api. I have tried searching the documentation, to no avail.
If I can mark a task as archived, that will essentially mean 'processed' from my apps perspective and the size/frequency of my asana api requests will be controlled.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to filter out archived tasks in the API. A workaround might be to record the IDs of processed tasks locally?